# Build and expand function for forecasting

Tags: r, for-loop

This code make forecasting with forecast package. Final outputs from this code are three lists forecasted with snaive method  (SNAIVE_PIT, SNAIVE_CIT and SNAIVE_VAT).

```
#CODE
library(forecast)
        # Making data frame
      DATA_SET<-data.frame(
        PIT=seq(1, 48, by = 2),
        CIT=seq(1, 24, by = 1),
        VAT=seq(1, 94, by = 4)
      )
     View(DATA_SET)

      # FOR LOOP
     for(i in 1:ncol(DATA_SET)){
        # Build a ts for this column
        timeseries <- ts(DATA_SET[,i], start=c(2016,1), frequency = 12)
        # Build a foreacst based on the ts
        forecast <- snaive(timeseries,h=5)
           # rename the forecast according to the original variable name
        colname <- colnames(DATA_SET)[i]
        forecastName <- paste("SNAIVE_",colname," <- forecast",sep="")
        eval(parse(text = forecastName))
      }
```

However coding does not end with the above code. Namely I have to expand this code with some additional things.

First, is how to put this line in the above code (part FOR LOOP)?

```
#NEW CODE 1
SNAIVE_ALL<-mapply(SNAIVE_PIT, SNAIVE_CIT,SNAIVE_VAT, FUN=list, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

Second, is how to put this line in the above code(part FOR LOOP)?

```
#NEW CODE 2
   SNAIVE_PIT_ACCURANCY<-accuracy(SNAIVE_PIT)
    SNAIVE_CIT_ACCURANCY<-accuracy(SNAIVE_CIT)
     SNAIVE_VAT_ACCURANCY<-accuracy(SNAIVE_VAT)

  SNAIVE_ACCURANCY<-rbind(SNAIVE_PIT_ACCURANCY,SNAIVE_CIT_ACCURANCY,SNAIVE_VAT_ACCURANCY)
```

So anybody can help me with this code ?

Answer (score 0):

I personally think you are doing this in the completly wrong  way, R code is not meant to generate and combine lists all the time, you can do all these operations in a functional way, first you need to think what the list structure would be.

I recommend the following structure

each dataset is a list, each list receives a function that generates two lists, predictions and accuracy.

Let's code.

```
# I recommend spliting this function but I am lazy

prediction_funtion <- function(x) {
  x <- ts(x, start=c(2016,1), frequency = 12)
  model <- snaive(x)
  forecasts_results <- forecast(model,5)
  accuracy_results <- accuracy(model)
  return(list(forecast = forecasts_results,accuracy =accuracy_results))
}

map(list_df,prediction_funtion)
```